# How to access a method in controller in laravel scheduler?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I need to access a method of my UserController in laravel scheduler function,

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('foo')
             ->hourly();
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried to put UserController in the command`s construct and let Laravel inject it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try his:

```
$schedule->call('Full\Namespace\YourController@method')
    ->hourly();
```